# IOTA Light Wallet returns Request Error when sending funds

Tags: transaction, iri-node, light-node

I am running IOTA Light Wallet 2.5.4 and am connected to my own full node that is in-sync with 4 healthy tangle connections. The minimum weight magnitude (MWM) is set to 14.

When attempting to send funds from the wallet the UI displays `Sending...` for several minutes, and eventually turns red saying `Request Error`.

This is the server log at the time of the transaction:

```
11/30 05:15:00.049 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Reason to stop: belowMaxDepth
11/30 05:15:00.049 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Tx traversed to find tip: 20
11/30 05:15:00.613 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Reason to stop: belowMaxDepth
11/30 05:15:00.613 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Tx traversed to find tip: 11
11/30 05:15:01.328 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Reason to stop: TransactionViewModel is a tip
11/30 05:15:01.328 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Tx traversed to find tip: 6
11/30 05:15:01.478 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Reason to stop: belowMaxDepth
11/30 05:15:01.478 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Tx traversed to find tip: 3
11/30 05:15:01.881 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Reason to stop: TransactionViewModel is a tip
11/30 05:15:01.881 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Tx traversed to find tip: 6
11/30 05:15:02.641 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Reason to stop: belowMaxDepth
11/30 05:15:02.641 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Tx traversed to find tip: 6
11/30 05:15:04.111 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Reason to stop: belowMaxDepth
11/30 05:15:04.111 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Tx traversed to find tip: 9
11/30 05:15:04.280 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO  com.iota.iri.network.Node - toProcess = 0 , toBroadcast = 0 , toRequest = 1 , toReply = 0 / totalTransactions = 3296908
11/30 05:15:04.334 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Reason to stop: belowMaxDepth
11/30 05:15:04.334 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Tx traversed to find tip: 30
11/30 05:15:04.838 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Reason to stop: TransactionViewModel is a tip
11/30 05:15:04.838 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Tx traversed to find tip: 23
11/30 05:15:05.492 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Reason to stop: TransactionViewModel is a tip
11/30 05:15:05.493 [XNIO-1 task-8] INFO  com.iota.iri.service.TipsManager - Tx traversed to find tip: 25
```

Why can I not use this node to run transactions?

Comment: What is your Min Weight Magnitude and your Curl implementation on the light wallet (Tools > Edit Node Configuration)

Comment: Min Weight: 14.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is reading this post in 2019. Please stop using the IOTA light wallet and use the security audited and cross-platform wallet Trinity.

https://trinity.iota.org/

Answer (score 0):

That log looks like your node is busy with spamming, so it doesn't finish your request in time.

Comment: How can you tell? The log only prints the stats every 10s until I click send in my wallet. It seems as if the messages from the log posted were generated only when the client attempted to send funds.